# What US sci-fi TV series has an ill doctor from Desert Storm and a conspiracy?

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a TV series but I only remember a few details because I just caught the final minutes of the episode.

1. I saw it on a French channel, but it's American.
2. The hero is a doctor who was in Desert Storm.
3. I believe he was sick.
4. There's some kind of conspiracy that he gets involved with.
5. At the the end of the episode a female doctor, Asian looking, gives him a vial with what might be a cure for his illness, probably Gulf War Syndrome.
6. I don't know for sure but I believe it was only a pilot.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What was sci-fi about it?

Comment: What does "Asian looking" mean? The inhabitants of Earth's largest continent do not all look the same. Did she look Turkish? Siberian? Persian? Ceylonese? Mongolian?

Comment: @user14111 - I'm reasonably sure he means [asian](https://www.helpmeoutdoc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/chinese-man.jpg) rather than [asian](https://jafrianews.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/australian-mp-mehreen-faruqi.jpg)

Comment: This should be reopened. In a comment to his answer, Valorum details why this series is science fiction.

Comment: For example, from episode 13: "Turner investigates the sudden appearance of a boy genius kidnapped six years ago, whose DNA is somehow more evolved than human DNA. " I have no idea what it means for DNA to be "more evolved," but it sounds like sci-fi to me.

Comment: Or even better, the episode "Azrael's Breed": "A terminally ill doctor addicted to death is killing people and using his new revolutionary technique to extract their memory and inject it into himself to relive their moment of death."

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that you're referring to the short-lived [Strange World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_World).

> Strange World was a short-lived sci-fi series in the tradition of The
> X-Files. ABC cancelled it after airing three episodes due to poor
> ratings. The remaining ten episodes were picked up and aired by the
> SciFi Channel.
>
> Strange World revolves around Captain Paul Turner. While serving in
> the Gulf War he was exposed to chemical weapons and developed aplastic
> anemia. Also a doctor, Turner works for USAMRIID (United States Army
> Medical Research Institute of Infectious Diseases) where he
> investigates the unethical uses of science, medicine, and related
> technologies. He is approached by a mysterious Asian woman who gives
> him a temporary cure for his symptoms. She works for a shadow
> organization whose goals run counter to USAMRIID.
>
> In Lullaby, Cass is a young pregnant woman. She fears her doctor is
> trying to kill her unborn child. As Turner investigates, he learns
> that Cass is a surrogate mother and there may be something to her
> story. Many of her doctor's patients mysteriously miscarry at 6
> months. There's a medical experiment being performed on Cass and the
> others. Callum plays Vince, Cass's boyfriend, who tries very hard to
> do what he believes is right.
>
> <sub><sup>[CKR: Review - Lullaby](http://the-ckr-files.livejournal.com/12755.html?thread=242899)</sup></sub>

Comment: "Sci-fi" series...What's sci-fi about it? If it is sci-fi, I will withdraw my close vote.

Comment: For the record, this show was *awful*. If you're planning to rewatch it, I'd heartily suggest that you save the eight hours and instead [learn to code in javascript](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Beginners-Programming-Language-Essential-ebook/dp/B00WH0ESWC), take a trip to your local zoo or become a [qualified boat pilot](http://www.rya.org.uk/cruising/handling-power/Pages/boat-handling-power.aspx).

Comment: @Adamant - It was all "5 minutes into the future" science. Cloning being abused, nanomachines running amok, intelligent spiders. Basically sub X-Files fodder. Definitely scifi though.

Comment: No problem then.